# Uso de For para modificar tablas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, apache-spark, pyspark

Tengo el siguiente código en Pyspark:

```
%%time

lst_tablas = [tabla_pivote_0_15, tabla_pivote_15_30, tabla_pivote_30_60, tabla_pivote_60_90, tabla_pivote_90_120,
             tabla_pivote_120_150, tabla_pivote_150_180,
             tabla_pivote_180_210, tabla_pivote_210_240, tabla_pivote_240_270,
             tabla_pivote_270_300, tabla_pivote_300_330, tabla_pivote_330_360]

trans = ['COMPRAS_CREDITO', 'RETIROS_CREDITO','RETIROS_DEBITO','COMPRAS_MADRUGADA','COMPRAS_MANANA','COMPRAS_TARDE','COMPRAS_NOCHE','RETIROS_MADRUGADA','RETIROS_MANANA','RETIROS_TARDE','RETIROS_NOCHE','COMPRAS_ENTRE_SEMANA','RETIROS_ENTRE_SEMANA','MAX_DEBITO_DISPONIBLE','MAX_PORC_ENDEUDAMIENTO','PORCENTAJE_COMPRAS_ECOMMERCE','razon_comercios','razon_transacciones','razon_compras','razon_retiros','razon_ecomerce']
i = 1
for t in lst_tablas:
    for var in trans:
        nombre = var + '_m' + str(i)
        t = t.withColumnRenamed(var, nombre)
        
    i += 1
    #display(t.show())
tabla_pivote_30_60.show()
```

En el cual tengo en una lista las tablas con información de los 12 meses del año. Y el primer mes de 0 a 15 dias y de 15 a 30 dias.

Lo que intento hacer es que a cada una de esas tablas que tienen diferentes campos, únicamente a los campos que se encuentren en la lista `trans` les ponga un sufijo, por eso la parte del código de `var + '_m' + str(i)`.

Al ver los resultados y hacer un `show` en la tabla `tabla tabla_pivote_30_60` me doy cuenta que no se modificó el nombre de las variables que quería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, si yo descomento la línea

```
display(t.show())
```

Para validar que paso con el `for` me doy cuenta que dentro del `for` si lo hace bien, pero terminando el `for` no cambia el nombre a las tablas, es decir como si solo fueran temporales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría decirme que está pasando y ayudarme a modificar las tablas de manera permanente. De antemano gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu fallo **NO** tiene que ver con `pyspark`, **tiene que ver con el funcionamiento de Python**

Para ello, primero te lo voy a explicar con Python puro, sin utilizar `pyspark`.

### Explicación

En Python el operador `=` reserva un espacio de memoria para asignar una información. Pueden suceder dos cosas:

1. Si la variable no existe, **se reservará un espacio de memoria** nuevo en tu ordenador y se asignará a la variable. Por tanto será completamente nueva y no guardará relación con nada anterior.
2. Si la variable existe, pueden suceder dos cosas, que se utilice el espacio de memoria existente o que se destruya (por incompatibilidad) y se cree otro nuevo.

En tu caso, cuando iteras en el bucle, creas una variable nueva llamada `t` que luego sobrescribes, es decir, Python destruye la variable `t` y crea una variable `t` nueva, que **no tiene nada que ver con los DataFrame de Pyspark**, que está en tu lista `lst_tablas`. Vamos a demostrar esto:

```
lista_de_listas = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

print("Posición en memoria primer elemento: ", hex(id(lista_de_listas[0])))
print("Posición en memoria segundo elemento: ",hex(id(lista_de_listas[1])))
```

**Salida:**

```
Posición en memoria primer elemento: 0x7f05be787cd0
Posición en memoria segundo elemento: 0x7f05ad300780
```

Perfecto, ahora vamos a reproducir la asignación que estás con haciendo con `pyspark` con esta lista:

```
for lista in lista_de_listas:
    print("Posición en memoria antes: ", hex(id(lista)))
    lista = [1,2]
    print("Posición en memoria después: ", hex(id(lista)))
```

**Salida:**

```
Posición en memoria antes: 0x7f05be787cd0
Posición en memoria después: 0x7f05ad2f4280
Posición en memoria antes: 0x7f05ad300780
Posición en memoria después: 0x7f05ad2f4280
```

Ha pasado exactamente lo mencionado, en este caso, al iterar con el `for` he ido a la posición de memoria de cada elemento de `lista_de_listas` y luego sobrescribo `lista`, esta variable se ha asignado a una posición de memoria nueva, es decir, **no tiene nada que ver** con los elementos que se encuentran dentro de `lista_de_listas`

### Solución

Hay varias soluciones, te dejo un par siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior:

#### Usar enumerate

Consiste en indicarle al elemento de la lista que nos referimos para que no se cree una nueva variable, y **se realice una asignación a un espacio de memoria existente.**

```
for idx, lista in enumerate(lista_de_lista):
    lista_de_lista[idx] = [1,2]
    
print(lista_de_lista)
```

**Salida:** `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]`

`enumerate` nos devuelve un iterador con la posición del elemento y el elemento (en este orden). Podríamos hacer lo mismo con `range()` y `len()`

**Tu caso sería:**

```
# Notese que he eliminado la i, ya que con el enumerate no es necesario para el nombre de la variable
for idx, t in enumerate(lst_tablas):
    for var in trans:
        nombre = var + '_m' + str(idx+1)
        lst_tablas[idx] = t.withColumnRenamed(var, nombre)
```

#### Usar range

- `range`: nos crea un rango de números hasta el indicado.
- `len`: nos dice la longitud de la lista.

```
for idx in range(len(lista_de_lista)):
    lista_de_lista[idx] = [1,2]

print(lista_de_lista)
```

**Salida:** `[[1, 2], [1, 2]]`

**Tu caso sería:**

```
for idx in range(len(lst_tablas)):
    for var in trans:
        nombre = var + '_m' + str(idx+1)
        lst_tablas[idx] = t.withColumnRenamed(var, nombre)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación y aclararme mi duda Alberto. ¡Saludos!